# How to mock require in electronJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jasmine, electron

I'm trying to write unit test for my electron js application and I'm stuck at one place.

**For example**

Lets say my app code is like below

```
var app= (function () {
    function app() {
        var _this = this;
        this.open = function (data) {
            var deferred = Q.defer();
            try {
                // some code 
            }
            catch (ex) {
                deferred.reject(ex);
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        };

    }
}());
exports.app = app
```

Now if I want to run it on electron client it will run perfectly fine as electron module is installed on client's PC

The problem is when I'm trying to write unit test cases for the above as electron is not installed here on dev machine like below

```
    import { app} from '../../app'
    import { Rights } from '../../Rights'
    describe('app', () => {
        let app: app;
        beforeEach(() => {
            app= new app();
        })

        it('should call open() and return error for null content', function (done) {
            let output = app.open(null);
            output
            .then((res) => { 
                 //expectation 
                 done(); 
            })
            .catch((err)=>{
                //expectation 
                done();
           })
        })
    })
```

Getting following error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'electron'                                                                                                                                                      
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)                                                                                                                                
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)                                                                                                                                           
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)                                                                                                                                                  
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)                                                                                                                                                 
    at Object.<anonymous> (<project pat>/app.js:2:16)                                                                    
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)                                                                                                                                                 
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)                                                                                                                                   
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)                                                                                                                                                     
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)                                                                                                                                                   
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)                                                                                                                                            
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

**Question**

- How to mock require for any module which is not installed on dev PC
  but required for actual execution(installed on client's PC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can intercept `require` calls by overriding `module._load` :

```
const m = require('module');
const originalLoader = m._load;
const stubs = { electron : {} };

m._load = function hookedLoader(request, parent, isMain) {
  const stub = stubs[request];
  return stub || originalLoader(request, parent, isMain);
};
```

Comment: Used your solution with some minor changes..:)

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar issue with mocha. My basic approach was to:
 * require electron in before hook,
 * override it with local default
 * require app 
 * clean in after hook

Here's a sample:

```js
var el = require('../../modules/electron');

describe('app', function () {
  'use strict';

  var el_override = {
      post: function () {
      },
      get: function () {
      }
    }, app;

  before(function () {
    /* Since we already have electron required, we override it
      from node cache by:
      require.cache['/path/to/file/name'].exports = el_override
    */

    // Require app
    // This will import overridden electron
    App = require('app-location');
  });

  beforeEach(function () {
    // init app
    app = new App();
  });

  after(function () {
    // Clean Up both electron override and app by
    // delete requre.cache['/path/to/file/names']
  });

  it('should test for batch', function () {
    // Call you functions
  });
});
```

Comment: But then you need to install electron on dev machine as well..right..?

Comment: Yes on dev machine you install normal dependency as well as dev. On production install normal dependency.

Comment: I kept dep like : 
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "express-session": "^1.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ansi-regex": "^2.0.0",
    "grunt-mocha-test": "^0.10.2"
  }